# how to show multiple records in table from controller getting data from stream reader in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller

in controller action im getting multiple records,that im unble to show in table. this code working for single record showing not working for multiple records.how to use collection for multiple records.

sample data

```
[{"id":1488437716804,"timestamp":"2017-03-02T06:55:16.804Z","dataFrame":"UkFEOkRO","fcnt":12453,"port":2,"rssi":-83,"snr":8.5,"sf_used":7,"decrypted":true},{"id":1488437738877,"timestamp":"2017-03-02T06:55:38.877Z","dataFrame":"UkFEOkRO","fcnt":12455,"port":2,"rssi":-87,"snr":9.80000019073486,"sf_used":7,"decrypted":true}]
```

controller

```
private List<PIRDetailsViewModel> getPirDetails()
{
    List<PIRDetailsViewModel> model = new List<PIRDetailsViewModel>();

    try
    {
        WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(@"https:url");
        req.Method = "GET";
        req.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + "a2VybmVsc3BoZXJlOmtlcm5lbHNwaGVyZQ==";
        HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        var encoding = resp.CharacterSet == "" ? Encoding.UTF8 : Encoding.GetEncoding(resp.CharacterSet);
        using (var stream = resp.GetResponseStream())
        {
            var reader = new StreamReader(stream, encoding);
            var responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
            dynamic bin = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseString);
            byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(bin.dataFrame.ToString());
            PIRDetailsViewModel binModel = new PIRDetailsViewModel();
            binModel.status = Convert.ToString(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data).Substring(4));
            binModel.UpdatedTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(Convert.ToDateTime(bin.timestamp), TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time")).ToString();
            model.Add(binModel);
        }
    }


    return model;
}
```

view

```
 <table class="table table-striped" id="listing">
        <thead>
            <tr class="success">
                <th class="success" style="font-size:20px">sl no</th>
                <th class="success" style="font-size:20px">Time</th>
                <th class="success" style="font-size:20px">status</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model.Select((value, i) => new { i, value }))
            {
                    <tr id="tr_@item.value.deviceid">
                    <td class="danger">@item.value.status</td>
                    <td class="warning">@item.value.UpdatedTime</td>

                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: You need to use a collection and bind it to the model. In the view you have to use the collection you binded in the model and render it to display it as grid/table

Answer (score 0):

You add only one element to your model.

You call only once to `model.Add(binModel);`

That's the reason you have only one element in your view.